# Error updating custom metadata types through Talend

Tags: api, talend, custom-metadata

I am trying to update a custom metadata type record through the standard Salesforce connectors in Talend. But I receive an error that says "unable to update entity type".

Are we able to update these records through API? If yes, how do I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Metadata Type records cannot be created or updated through normal routes applicable to regular sObjects or Custom Settings, like the REST and SOAP APIs.

CMT records are metadata and must be manipulated using the Metadata API or change sets. There is limited support for mutating these records in Apex.

Any deployment tool should be able to retrieve and deploy these records. I do not know whether Talend has this capability.